# App not building if Product name has space like "My App.app"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an app with multiple targets in it.

The targets where the app name is a compound like "My Calendar.app", I get the following error.

PS: it was working just fine until yesterday.

> PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gzustbupponndubupkrlgejuzkny/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyTarget.build/Script-C83A32A4B47BCDE537E8BEBD.sh
>       cd /Users/myuser/Projects/DojoApps/myapp-ios
>       /bin/sh -c /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gzustbupponndubupkrlgejuzkny/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyTarget.build/Script-C83A32A4B47BCDE537E8BEBD.sh
>
> mkdir -p /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gzustbupponndubupkrlgejuzkny/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/My Target.app/Frameworks
>   rsync -av --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gzustbupponndubupkrlgejuzkny/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AFDropdownNotification/AFDropdownNotification.framework" "/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gzustbupponndubupkrlgejuzkny/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/My Target.app/Frameworks"
>   building file list ... done
>   AFDropdownNotification.framework/
>   AFDropdownNotification.framework/AFDropdownNotification
>   AFDropdownNotification.framework/Info.plist
>   AFDropdownNotification.framework/_CodeSignature/
>   AFDropdownNotification.framework/_CodeSignature/CodeResources
>
> sent 89566 bytes  received 98 bytes  179328.00 bytes/sec
>   total size is 89184  speedup is 0.99
>   Code Signing /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gzustbupponndubupkrlgejuzkny/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/My Target.app/Frameworks/AFDropdownNotification.framework with Identity -
>   /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign -  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gzustbupponndubupkrlgejuzkny/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/My Target.app/Frameworks/AFDropdownNotification.framework

Error:

> /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gzustbupponndubupkrlgejuzkny/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/My: No such file or directory

I have found similar problems but no solution fitted my case.

Comment: You should clean and build again. `Option+Command+Shift+K` is the shout cut.

Comment: @Ryan I have tried that already. No deal =/

Comment: Can you open the text version of that error using the little "lines of text" button in the upper right and paste the actual command line invocations Xcode is running for this error? That'd be helpful.

Comment: Did you install an Xcode update? In the past there has been cases when Xcode did not escape the file names.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I did update on december 13th

Comment: And you mean "yesterday" literally? It worked after installing the update of the 13th?